# Como alterar a ordem dos parâmentros da Url Amigável no htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

Minha **URL amigáve**l está assim: guaraparivirtual.com.br/**noticias-guarapari/moqueca-capixaba-agua-na-boca/9/**

Gostaria que houvesse a troca de ordem de lugar dos parâmetros do última para a penúltimo.

Desta forma: guaraparivirtual.com.br/noticias-guarapari/**9/moqueca-capixaba-agua-na-boca/**

Fiz de tudo porém sem sucesso.

Segue meu código do `.htaccess`

## URL AMIGAVEL

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^noticias-guarapari/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /noticias-guarapari.php?idnoticia=$2&nome=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Sei que parece óbvio, mas alterei a ordem para:

```
 RewriteRule ^noticias-guarapari/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /noticias-guarapari.php?nome=$1&idnoticia=$2 [NC]
```

E chamei a url: guaraparivirtual.com.br/noticias-guarapari/9/moqueca-capixaba-agua-na-boca/

O conteúdo do mysql não carrega quando é feito esta última alteração que fiz, apenas a primeira que funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos entender a ordem dos parâmetros.

Antes estava assim:

guaraparivirtual.com.br/noticias-guarapari/**moqueca-capixaba-agua-na-boca**/**9**/

Tendo em ordem:

1. **moqueca-capixaba-agua-na-boca**
2. **9**

Agora você quer que fique assim:

guaraparivirtual.com.br/noticias-guarapari/**9**/**moqueca-capixaba-agua-na-boca**/

Tendo em ordem:

1. **9**
2. **moqueca-capixaba-agua-na-boca**

Então é simples, apenas altere:

> nome=$1 **para** nome=$2
>
> idnoticia=$2 **para** idnoticia=$1

Ficando assim:

```
                              # $1           $2
RewriteRule ^noticias-guarapari/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /noticias-guarapari.php?nome=$2&idnoticia=$1 [NC]
```